# Alter initial Visual Studio code behind stub code?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, code-generation, stub

When I add a new form to an ASP.NET project (WebForms), and then "View Code" some basic stub code is added -- basic "using" statements, form_load event, etc.

So the first thing I have to do is add some project usings, etc.  Is there anyway to alter this canned code to what I want, vs. what it puts up by default?

Would templates be the answer?

TIA
Kevin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are right. that is a template.

You can file project templates in the following directory

%VisualStudioPath%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033

And item templates

%VisualStudioPath%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033

Answer (score 2):

I think `Templates` is Visual Studio would help you in your problem if I understood your problem correctly.

There are two different template types in Visual Studio :

1. `Item Template`
2. `Project Template`

You can find more information about Visual Studio Templates here : [`Templates in Visual Studio`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky%28VS.80%29.aspx)